# Is "bobsled" or "bobsleigh" more commonly used in Jamaican English?

Tags: caribbean-english

["Bobsled" versus "Bobsleigh"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23174/bobsled-versus-bobsleigh) , along with Wiktionary's entries on [bobsleigh](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bobsleigh) and [bobsled](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bobsled#English) say that "bobsled" is more commonly used in the US and Canada, and that "bobsleigh" is more common in British English.

However, neither source mentions which term is more commonly used in Jamaican English, nor does Wikipedia's article on [Jamaican English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamaican_English). Which term is more commonly used in Jamaican English?

Comment: In line with the 'Modern additions to the lexicon tend to be more US-influenced, unlike the grammar' (paraphrased) comment in the Wikipedia article, I'd expect 'bobsled'. But I can't even find if the Caribbean English corpus mentioned by Gerhard Leitner as far back as 1992 has been completed.

Comment: I assume you won't accept "Cool Runnings" as evidence that they say "bobsleigh"...? *#Now Jamaica, we have a bobsleigh team*

Comment: @AndyT a respectable time to mention "Cool Runnings" is five point seven minutes. If you speed demons can't whip off an even six flat, you have a better chance of becoming a barbershop quartet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There are 79 results for [*bobsleigh*](http://www.jamaicaobserver.com/results/?text=bobsleigh&sa=GO) in the *Jamaica Observer* compared to 158 results for *[bobsled](http://www.jamaicaobserver.com/results/?text=bobsled&sa=GO)*

> - A BBC report said that Ms Kiriasis wanted payment for the sled but the **Jamaica Bobsleigh Federation** declined and was disputing that she owns the sled.
> - Red Stripe's rescue of the **Jamaica women's bobsleigh team** at the Winter Olympics in Pyeongchang, South Korea, is most commendable, but not surprising as this company has a proud history of supporting Jamaica and its people over many decades.
> - Jamaica's team is set to feature in the **two-woman bobsled competition** next Tuesday.
> - Jamaica's bronze **medal-winning bobsled team** of Carrie Russell (left) and Jazmine Fenlator-Victorian competing at the North American Cup in Lake Placid, United States recently.

2. In one of Jamaica's oldest newspapers, *The Gleaner*, founded in 1834, there are 1,690 results for *[bobsleigh](http://jamaica-gleaner.com/search?cx=partner-pub-4993191856924332%3A98b6e2-dgz1&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=ISO-8859-1&q_as=bobsleigh&sa=Search&siteurl=jamaica-gleaner.com%2F&ref=jamaica-gleaner.com&ss=)* and 1,880 hits for *[bobsled](http://jamaica-gleaner.com/search?cx=partner-pub-4993191856924332%3A98b6e2-dgz1&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=ISO-8859-1&q_as=bobsleigh&sa=Search&siteurl=jamaica-gleaner.com%2F&ref=jamaica-gleaner.com&ss=)*.
3. In *The Star* (a Jaimacan newspaper) there are 35 results for *[bobsled](http://jamaica-star.com/search?cx=partner-pub-4993191856924332%3A3w20d9-sevt&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=ISO-8859-1&q_as=bobsled&sa=Search&siteurl=jamaica-star.com%2F&ref=jamaica-star.com&ss=)* compared to just 15 for *[bobsleigh](http://jamaica-star.com/search?cx=partner-pub-4993191856924332%3A3w20d9-sevt&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=ISO-8859-1&q_as=bobsleigh&sa=Search&siteurl=jamaica-star.com%2F&ref=jamaica-star.com&ss=)*

> - Christian Stokes, president of the **Jamaica Bobsleigh and Skeleton Federation** (JBSF), disagrees with […] Dr Damien King's recent tweet that, **Jamaica's participation in bobsled** is ridiculous because it does not emerge from local capacity, activity or behaviour, or geography.

One thing is for certain though, the official Jamaican federation of the winter sport is called:
[**Jamaica Bobsleigh and Skeleton Federation (JBSF) Ltd**](https://www.jamaicabobsled.com/about). Founded in 1987 it is also a member of the *International Bobsleigh and Skeleton Federation* (IBSF)

Except their current website is at https://www.jamaicabobsled.com/about and a foundation was founded in 2014 called **The Jamaica Bobsled Foundation (JBF)**